# Eclipse Plugin RCP3 : Perspective list empty when running from a Product. No reset Perspective displayed

Tags: eclipse, fragment, rcp

I wanted to extend/reuse an already existing plugin.(which contain an Application, Activator, ApplicationActionBarAdvisor etc...).

I have created a fragment as I wanted to extend it without intrusion in the original code and I want to generate a product for Standalone use.

When I launch the fragment in Eclipse. It works!!! I got everything I need.

But when I use Product configuration. It launches the alrady existing product but I am loosing the list of perspectives => It's like a close all perspective action. So I can not use the perspective of already existing plugin. Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: How have you configured your product in the plugin.xml?

Comment: Hello again Greg, It's nice to see you again in line. As you can see, I am playing hard with eclipe RCP features :-( I have created a fragment. included my host (the existing pluging containing the Application). Run the fragment via eclipse => all work ok :-) Then on the fragment project create a new product configuration (3 choices, new, existing product or launch). I choose new, add the application Id. It runs but I loose all the perspective I had when launching from Eclipse....what else would you need to help? Thanks